# MTB front suspension sounds like rusty trampoline

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, suspension

I have an old GT i-drive 3.0 from like 2001, it has a Judy Rockshox fork on the front. I imagine its never been serviced (I bought it used) and it's starting to sound like a symphony of rusty trampoline springs. It's so noisy you could hear me coming from a mile away (riding on single-track mountain trails).

Any ideas what might cause a front suspension to make such racket? Is there anything I can do to make it stop? Like is this a DYI project or is it time to visit the mechanic?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you answered the "cause" part of your question already - "long-term lack of maintenance".

Whether you want to attempt the rehabilitation yourself or not depends on your degree of comfort with that kind of thing. Here is a copy of the [manual for the 2001 model](http://www.enduroforkseals.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/01rsjudyownersmanual.pdf) (PDF file; make sure it actually matches what you have), which should help you get a sense of what's involved.

Just be glad they're not melted-down elastomer suspensions from the '90s like the last bike I inherited... yeeesh. :P